# Image does not appear on site when uploaded to host server

Tags: html, image, png, hosting

when viewing my website on my local drive, everything works and appears as intended, but when all of my files are uploaded to GoDaddy, one of my images does not show up. I tried deleting and reuploading the file, but it simply won't appear on any browser or device. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The code that calls the image is probably referencing a local address. Something like `http://localhost/mysite/image.png`

You'll need to change that to the address of the image on your server. Something like `https://mysitedomain/image.png`

The best way to manage this sort of thing is with relative paths. Put the image in an `/images` folder in the root directory. Then you can reference it the same way locally and hosted. 
`<a href="/images/image.png">` or `background-image: url("/images/image.png")`

Answer (score 0):

You might use wrong path. If your image is Example.jpg and it is  in folder images, write `src="images/Example.jpg"` in `img` tag. It is easier and quicker.

You can use  other option but you have to write like this:

```
<img src="http:\\localhost\site\images\Example.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to case sensitivity. File name for hosted websites are case sensitive. Note, if your image's file name is ***"Image1.gif"***, then it won't load if you types the file name as ***"image2.gif"*** since image's file name is case sensitive.